# Invoices Table Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench

I looked over some of the other answers here and they did not answer the question I have.

How would I go about this problem. If an invoice is created with the following database schema:

```
id
customer_id
invoice_date
status
```

the invoice is created, paid etc. If the customer information changes, the invoice information will change since its a FK. How would I create the invoice table to record customers information at that give moment in time, so if the customer change their address in the future for example the past invoices will stay the same with the previous address.

Just wanted to see if it makes sense to copy customer information into the invoice table with their address etc. but then it will adhere to normalizing the database.

Please let me know what your thoughts are in regards to this challenge. Invoices in one example, this can also apply to Purchase orders that were created in the past should have definite information that was recorded in the past no matter what has changed now.

Answer (score 0):

There are different considerations for an order management system or a reporting system.

Within an application, data duplication may prove cumbersome at volume. Will prove cumbersome at high enough volume. So you'll want to be as normalized as possible in that environment.

For reporting and history, though, it would be preferable (maybe mandatory depending on your industry and locale) to have the address info for each invoice.

It would be better to have an address table that joins to your customer table. The addresses would each have their own id field, and then you could just reference that id in the invoice table, too. Probably both the billing address and the shipping address if they're both in play in your business model.

If you don't have the flexibility to introduce a stand alone address table, then copying the address information over to the invoice table becomes a necessary evil. But dead useful information to have.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about things like purchased items on the invoice. If I sell widget 1 at $1.99 and customer buys it and tomorrow the price goes up. If I reference that widget 1 to the invoice the price would change as well. However, the invoice should stay the same for the name of the widget and the price of the widget that got sold already. 

Would it be a wise decision to copy those items onto  the invoice table to make it stand alone regardless if the items that have sold change in price or other information.

There isn't a lot of information on this that I could find online

Comment: The invoice should be a snapshot in time. Record as much as you can get away with. :) Price paid, list price, MSRP if that’s different, cost, everything. You may not need a lot of it for billing, but someone will want metrics around everything eventually.

Comment: I’ve switched industries, from retail to insurance, but at one time I found some good info on a model order management system from the National Retail Federation. https://nrf.com/resources/retail-technology-standards-0 Try searching something like “retail data modeling.”